# Listview with checkboxes for deletion purposes

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to implement the delete functionality in  listview. I want it to act it like most common android apps (like the email client..etc). What I mean, is that when you click on delete button then the list will have check boxes in which you can check and then proceed with the delete.

I have my list view, but I am not sure about how the check box will appear (and will respond to clicks as opposed to the whole item responding to click), Any pointers on that? I thoght I would ask you first before I go on reinventing the wheel or bang my head against the wall.

Thank you so much

Comment: which layout your are using for your item? I mean you are using android layout which was predefined or your custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include checkbox in the listview `row.xml` and make its `Visibility` as `GONE`, then when you click on a `Button` that enables all the `CheckBoxes` just set a boolean true and referesh the `ListView`. On the basis of the boolean write the logic in `getView()` as

```
if(deleted_button_clicked){
  checkboxes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
  checkboxes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And further for deleting you having to get the checked items and perform deletion of Data from the ListView and refresh the ListView again.

**Update**

Further you can have a look at my blog about the [`ListView with CheckBox`](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I I looked at the codes on please correct me if I am wrong. I the item in the list will respond to clicks and check the check box. I however I am looking to check the box checkbox only when the checkbox is clicked not the list item

Comment: @Snake I had provided my blog address refer that also it includes the demo in github

Answer (score 0):

Putting a checkbox in a listview is a tedious job. I faced some of those probs and when I found a working solution, I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190390/checking-a-checkbox-in-listview-makes-other-random-checkboxes-checked-too). It has everything except the delete part. Hope it helps u.

Answer (score -1):

With you listView you can set following...

```
listView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, fields));
```

See the working example at [Here](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-create-multiple-choice-list)

Comment: can you hide/show checkbox by using above way? If yes then add to it.