# Android: Implementing ViewHolder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement ViewHolder in my Android app, but I keep getting that ViewHolder cannot be resolved to a type, without any suggestions for an import. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Here is a good example of the ViewHolder http://smr-android.blogspot.ru/2014/04/implementing-listview-with-swipe.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's because a `ViewHolder` is not a class that is *from* the Android SDK, you make it yourself.
Based on what I can [find](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/), a `ViewHolder` is an implementation that stores Views (per row in a ListView usually) for a larger area, so it is a sort of helper class and cache mechanism. This is one [example](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) I found on Android Developers of what a `ViewHolder` would contain.

```
static class ViewHolder {
  TextView text;
  TextView timestamp;
  ImageView icon;
  ProgressBar progress;
  int position;
}
```

Then you can implement it in a `ListAdapter` or a similar class.

Comment: Page #36: http://www.slideshare.net/arslantumbin/performance-optimization-for-android-32797106

Answer (score 1):

```
**Create a Holder class**

protected static class ViewHolderItems
{
    private ImageView mStoreImage;
    private TextView mStoreName;
}

And use In getView method of adapter

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItems viewHolder;
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coupen_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItems();
            viewHolder.mStoreImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeImage);

            viewHolder.mStoreName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeName);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } 
       else 
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItems) convertView.getTag();
        }

         return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the RecyclerView.ViewHolder which is part of the android support lib.

Like the code from this link [gist by Paul Burke](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/RecyclerListAdapter.java)

```
public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder { 

    public final TextView textView;
    public final ImageView handleView;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        handleView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.handle);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onItemSelected() { 
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onItemClear() { 
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(0); 
    } 
}
```

This would make sense for you if you were working with an [Android RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.htmlhttps://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

In this case they need an object to hold the view so that it can be filled with content as needed.