# overriding the onScroll method of the com.android.View in android coding?

Tags: java, android, view

How can I override the onScroll method of the View in android? I using it for the view to prevent the update in the view's checkboxes while when I scroll. I use a two dimensional array for storing the values of the checkbox's.

I use the following but did not work for me.

```
public void onScroll(View view, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount { 
    // here i check the view's check box 
    checkBox1.setchecked(true);
}
```

Comment: i am using it for an app which contain checkboxes, but when i scroll it, it loses its out of screen values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295110/how-to-set-the-visibilty-of-button-in-a-custom-listview this could be helpful, not the exact ques but could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. If you with to override a method supplied in an API class you will have to extend that class. I would suggest implementing your own custom `View` and override the `onScroll` method.

```
public class YourCustomView extends View
{
    @Override
    public void onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        /** Whatever you need to do, do it here! */
    }
}
```

However, I do not find this the best way to handle the situation. I would suggest using a `ViewHolder`. Basically, it is a container that holds information about your `View`'s items. I would recommend using it, especially if you have a list or multiple items to handle. You can read all about here in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087495/android-implementing-viewholder)!