# Listview Containing Viewpager inside SlidingMenu -Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In my project,listview contains viewpager for loading images.Actually this listview is loaded in a fragment which uses sliding menu .

Here the problem is layout is neither  loading nor showing any errors.

I used pagecontainer like this    s://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1

My Adapter class

```
 public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] titleData;
private int[] imageData;
private ArrayList<Request> List;
PagerContainer mContainer;
MyPagerAdapter adapter;

public SampleAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Request> list) {
    activity = a;
    List = new ArrayList<Request>();
    List = list;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return List.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cus_hub_list, parent, false);

    mContainer = (PagerContainer) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    ViewPager pager = mContainer.getViewPager();


    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();


    pager.setAdapter(adapter);


    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    pager.setPageMargin(15);
    pager.setClipChildren(false);

    return rowView;
}

public  class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
        TextView view = new TextView(activity);
        view.setText("Item " + position);
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50,
                position * 10, position * 50));

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
           return POSITION_NONE;
        }
}
```

}

But the problem is listview not showing any list items .

Can anybody figure out the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: My list view is all showing as empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your pager ,instead of wrap_content, 
specify a height in dp.This height can be fit according to the screen

Answer (score 0):

Your `SampleAdapter`, while having the list of items it manages, never does anything with them in the `getView` method. It is to be expected that nothing is showing up!

I would suggest you use a `ViewHolder` as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087495/android-implementing-viewholder) to populate all the items you want to show and then visualise them using the `convertView` parameter of the `getView` method.

Please consider [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder) for an introduction on the `Holder Pattern` and how to set the contents of a `List` for your `View`.

Comment: But getCount() contains a value 2 as size.So it should show  two list items ,right?

Comment: Your list might be populated but where do you tell your view how to show them? I added a link to a tutorial to my response.

Comment: But it is not showing any difference...Still not showing any listitems

Comment: So you did fix your NPE? Can you show the new code? How do you add items? Are you sure you aren't mixing design for `ViewPager` with simple `ListView`? Consider consulting http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Actually iam used the sameway like mentioned in this post https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1

Comment: But i need to show this  page slide in a listview..like facebook timeline

Comment: Try using Android's `ViewPager` as linked in the tutorial in the comment above.

Comment: Finally the problem is in the Viewpager xml .Once again Thanks Eric.

Comment: @Krishna Can you please help me regarding the same,I have the same problem as yours

Comment: I too want to slide my list view rows views using a view pager

Comment: @GauravArora   please check ur pager in xml... instead of wrap_content, specify a height in dp.

Comment: yes krishna you are right, when I specified a height as 40dip, it is looking now. Can you please tell me what if I have to show my complete layout ? how will fixed values will work ?