# Android - ToggleButton losses it's state after scrolling ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-togglebutton

I have been trying from two days to solve this problem. I have seen many questions related to this problem. But they didn't work for me.
I have a custom `ListView`. It's every row includes one `ImageView`, two `TextView`s and one `ToggleButton`. These all loads fine. When I change state of `ToggleButton` to `true`, then when I scroll down and  again scroll up then that `ToggleButton` losses it's state. That again goes to `false`.

Here is my `ArrayAdapter`

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater  = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list_item_layout, parent, false);

        RoundedImageView friendThumb = (RoundedImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.friendDp);
        TextView friendName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
        TextView friendNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.friendNumber);
        ToggleButton shareToggle = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.shareLocatioToggle);

        friendName.setText(myItems[position]);
        friendNumber.setText("8888888888");
        //friendThumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.friend_dp_thumb);

        shareToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shared with "+myItems[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        shareToggle.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        return row;
    }



}
```

Thanks

Comment: you have to explicitly set toggle state on your `getView()`, based on current item, the same way you set text for your `TextView`

Comment: but how to do that in code? I am confused

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with ViewHolder selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886799/issue-with-viewholder-selection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 things, an array to remember which items have been toggled, and explicitly `setChecked()` the ones that have been toggled.

```
private boolean[] myChecks = new boolean[myItems.length];
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        shareToggle.setChecked(myChecks[position]);
        shareToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                ...
                myChecks[position] = arg1;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain flag for toggle using setter getter method,bydefault it is set off then you have to on/off toggle and call notifydatasetchanged() for maintaining it's state.

Comment: Check this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/enabling-multi-selection-mode-in-listview-by-adding-togglebutton-using-custom-layout-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Toggle state recreates if it view is out of list view’s visibility. It is possible to make the full activity scrollable. So toggle button doesn’t losses its state