# Background color change of an item in arraylist in recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background-color

I am making an app in which I have a recycler view. The data is coming from the service and setting up trough an adapter. I have a check box and a cross image in the item layout. I need to change the color of the particular item background to green when clicking on the check box and to red when clicking on the cross image. I need both the color to be there until I make the final submit.

I am sharing my code as below :

The activity class :

```
package com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.xantatech.bazaar.R;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.retrofit.RetrofitHelper;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.adapter.OrderAdapter;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.model.OrderResponse;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.model.OrderResponseData;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.model.SourcingOrderListStatusResponse;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.utility.DialogHelper;
    import com.xantatech.bazaar.utility.NetworkUtil;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Callback;
    import retrofit2.Response;

    public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<OrderResponse>{
       RecyclerView order_recycler;
        String orderId;
        OrderAdapter orderAdapter;
    //    ProgressDialog pd;
        TextView order_no;
        ArrayList<OrderResponseData> orderResponseDatas = new ArrayList<>();
        public Button submitSourcingOrder;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
            orderId = getIntent().getStringExtra("orderId");

            order_recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.order_recycler);
            order_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_no);
            submitSourcingOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitSourcingOrder);

            order_recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
            order_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    //        pd.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
    //        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    //        pd.setCancelable(false);
    //        pd.setProgress(0);
    //        pd.setMax(100);
    //        pd.show();

            submitSourcingOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(OrderAdapter.arrayList.size() == OrderAdapter.orderListSize){
                        if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(OrderActivity.this)){
                            DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(OrderActivity.this);
                            RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingSubmitOrder(sourcingSubmitOrderCallback, "1",orderId, "2");
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, "Complete all the orders first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OrderResponse> call, Response<OrderResponse> response) {
            DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogDismiss();
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
              if(response.body().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
    //              pd.dismiss();
                  orderResponseDatas.addAll(response.body().getOrderList());
                  order_no.setText(""+orderResponseDatas.size());
                  orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(OrderActivity.this, orderResponseDatas);
                  order_recycler.setAdapter(orderAdapter);

                }else {
    //              pd.dismiss();
                  Toast.makeText(this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OrderResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogDismiss();
            Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, R.string.something_wrong_happened, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //        pd.dismiss();

        }

        Callback<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> sourcingSubmitOrderCallback = new Callback<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> call, Response<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> response) {
                DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogDismiss();
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    if(response.body().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        OrderAdapter.arrayList.clear();
                        OrderAdapter.orderListSize = 0;
                        Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, ""+response.body().getOrderList(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, R.string.something_wrong_happened, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogDismiss();
                Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, R.string.something_wrong_happened, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(OrderActivity.this)){
                DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(OrderActivity.this);
                RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingTeamOrder(OrderActivity.this, "1",orderId);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

The Adapter Class :

```
package com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.xantatech.bazaar.R;
import com.xantatech.bazaar.retrofit.RetrofitHelper;
import com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.model.OrderResponseData;
import com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.model.SourcingOrderListStatusResponse;
import com.xantatech.bazaar.utility.DialogHelper;
import com.xantatech.bazaar.utility.NetworkUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

/**
 * Created by new on 12/10/17.
 */

public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Callback<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse>{


    Context context;
    ArrayList<OrderResponseData> orderResponseDatas = new ArrayList<>();
//    private boolean onBind;
    public static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int orderListSize = 0;
    public int row_index = -1;
    String type = "";

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderResponseData> orderResponseDatas) {

        this.context = context;
        this.orderResponseDatas = orderResponseDatas;

    }


    @Override
    public OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_order, parent, false);
        return new OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final OrderResponseData orderResponseData=orderResponseDatas.get(position);

        holder.order_brand.setText(orderResponseDatas.get(position).getBrand());
        holder.order_pname.setText(orderResponseDatas.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.order_size.setText(orderResponseDatas.get(position).getSize());
        holder.order_quantity.setText(orderResponseDatas.get(position).getQuantity());

        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.check.setChecked(orderResponseData.isChecked());
        holder.check.setEnabled(!orderResponseData.isEnabled());
        holder.imgCross.setEnabled(!orderResponseData.isCrossEnabled());

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("check")){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(orderResponseData.isBackgroundSelected() ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE);
        }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("cross")){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(orderResponseData.isBackgroundSelected() ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
        }


        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                orderResponseData.setChecked(isChecked);
                orderResponseData.setEnabled(isChecked);
                orderResponseData.setCrossEnabled(isChecked);
                row_index = position;
                type = "check";
                orderResponseData.setBackgroundSelected(!orderResponseData.isBackgroundSelected());
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(orderResponseData.isBackgroundSelected() ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(context)){
                   // DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(context);
                  //  RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingOrderListStatus(OrderAdapter.this, "1", orderResponseDatas.get(position).getId(), "1");
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.imgCross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                row_index = position;
                type = "cross";
                orderResponseData.setEnabled(true);
                orderResponseData.setCrossEnabled(true);
                orderResponseData.setBackgroundSelected(!orderResponseData.isBackgroundSelected());
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(orderResponseData.isBackgroundSelected() ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(context)){
                    //DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(context);
                    //RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingOrderListStatus(OrderAdapter.this, "1", orderResponseDatas.get(position).getId(), "3");
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

//        if(row_index == position) {
//            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("check")) {
//                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
//            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("cross")){
//                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
//            }
//        } else {
//            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
//        }




//       holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//           @Override
//           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean checked) {
//               if(checked){
//                   holder.check.setChecked(false);
//                   // Code to display your message.
//
//                   AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
//                   builder1.setMessage("CheckBox Clicked");
//                   builder1.setCancelable(true);
//
//                   builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                       @Override
//                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
//                           dialogInterface.cancel();
////                           holder.check.setChecked(true);
//                           holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
//                           if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(context)){
////                               DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(context);
////                               RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingOrderListStatus(OrderAdapter.this, "1", orderResponseDatas.get(position).getId(), "1");
//                           }else {
//                               Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                           }
//                       }
//                   });
//
//                   builder1.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//                                   dialog.cancel();
//                                   holder.check.setChecked(false);
//                               }
//                           });
//
//                   AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
//                   alert11.show();
//
//               }
//
//           }
//       });


//        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
//                if(!onBind){
////                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
//                    holder.check.setChecked(false);
//                    holder.check.setEnabled(true);
//                    row_index = position;
//                    if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(context)){
//                        DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(context);
//                        RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingOrderListStatus(OrderAdapter.this, "1", orderResponseDatas.get(position).getId(), "1");
//
//                        updateItem(orderResponseData);
//                        orderResponseDatas.remove(position);
//                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
//                        Log.d("position", "*******"+position);
//                        notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    }else {
//                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        });



//        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
//                if(checked){
////                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
//                    row_index = position;
////                    holder.check.setChecked(true);
////                    holder.check.setEnabled(false);
//                    notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(context)){
////                        DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(context);
////                        RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingOrderListStatus(OrderAdapter.this, "1", orderResponseDatas.get(position).getId(), "1");
//                    }else {
//                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        });


//        holder.imgCross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
//                holder.check.setEnabled(false);
//                if(NetworkUtil.checkNetworkStatus(context)){
//                    DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogShow(context);
//                    RetrofitHelper.getInstance().sourcingOrderListStatus(OrderAdapter.this, "1", orderResponseDatas.get(position).getId(), "3");
//                }else {
//                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//        });

//        if(orderResponseData.islast()){
//            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
//            onBind = true;
//            holder.check.setChecked(true);
//            holder.check.setEnabled(false);
//            onBind = false;
//        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("orderSize",""+orderResponseDatas.size());
        orderListSize = orderResponseDatas.size();
        return orderResponseDatas.size();


    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> call, Response<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> response) {
        DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogDismiss();
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            if(response.body().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+response.body().getOrderList(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arrayList.add("1");
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.something_wrong_happened, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SourcingOrderListStatusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        DialogHelper.getInstance().dialogDismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.something_wrong_happened, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView order_brand,order_pname,order_size,order_quantity;
        CheckBox check;
        ImageView imgCross;
//        LinearLayout linearLayout1;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            order_brand = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_brand);
            order_pname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_pname);
            order_size = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_size);
            order_quantity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_quantity);
            check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            imgCross = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCross);
//            linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

        }

    }



//    public void updateItem(OrderResponseData orderResponseData){
//        ArrayList<OrderResponseData> arrTeamResponseData=new ArrayList<>();
//        arrTeamResponseData.add(orderResponseData);
//        orderResponseDatas.addAll(arrTeamResponseData);
//        orderResponseData=orderResponseDatas.get(orderResponseDatas.size()-1);
//        orderResponseData.setIslast(true);
//        arrayList.add(orderResponseData);
//        Log.d("size", "************"+arrayList.size());
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//
//    }


}
```

The Model class :

```
    package com.xantatech.bazaar.sourcingteam.model;

    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    /**
     * Created by new on 12/10/17.
     */

    public class OrderResponseData {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("brand")
        @Expose
        private String brand;
        @SerializedName("product_name")
        @Expose
        private String productName;
        @SerializedName("size")
        @Expose
        private String size;
        @SerializedName("quantity")
        @Expose
        private String quantity;
        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;

        private boolean islast;

        private boolean isEnabled;

        private boolean isChecked;

        private boolean isCrossEnabled;

        private boolean isBackgroundSelected;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getBrand() {
            return brand;
        }

        public void setBrand(String brand) {
            this.brand = brand;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public String getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(String size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        public String getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public boolean islast() {
            return islast;
        }

        public void setIslast(boolean islast) {
            this.islast = islast;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            isEnabled = enabled;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            isChecked = checked;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return isEnabled;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return isChecked;
        }

        public boolean isCrossEnabled() {
            return isCrossEnabled;
        }

        public void setCrossEnabled(boolean crossEnabled) {
            isCrossEnabled = crossEnabled;
        }

        public boolean isBackgroundSelected() {
            return isBackgroundSelected;
        }

        public void setBackgroundSelected(boolean backgroundSelected) {
            isBackgroundSelected = backgroundSelected;
        }
    }`



`
```

The Item layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id = "@+id/check"
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight = "1.5"

                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imgCross"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/order_brand"
            android:layout_width = "0dp"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "1.5"
            android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:ellipsize = "end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding = "@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text = "Brand"
            android:singleLine = "true" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/order_pname"
            android:layout_width = "0dp"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:ellipsize = "end"
            android:padding = "@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text = "Product"
            android:singleLine = "true" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/order_size"
            android:layout_width = "0dp"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "1.5"
            android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:ellipsize = "end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding = "@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text = "Size"
            android:singleLine = "true" />

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/order_quantity"
            android:layout_width = "0dp"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:ellipsize = "end"
            android:padding = "@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text = "Quantity"
            android:singleLine = "true" />
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/order_mrp"
            android:layout_width = "0dp"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:ellipsize = "end"
            android:padding = "@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:text = "MRP"
            android:singleLine = "true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background color of selected item in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692214/changing-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recyclerview)

Comment: holder.yourview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.desire_color);

Comment: Hello V.Y. , Thanks for the update, but I have already gone through the above link which you gave me. But my question is , I want to keep both the colors till the final submit. suppose, I have 10 items and if i click 5 cross and 5 check box then i should i have 5 green background and 5 red background item in my list in recycler view.

Comment: use data binding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Android RecyclerView doesn’t come with the Item Click Listener that you have with ListView. You will have to implement the item click listener yourself. You have to implement the view holder item clicker listener in RecyclerView.

http://www.codexpedia.com/android/defining-item-click-listener-for-recyclerview-in-android/

Comment: Hello Jakir, Thanks for the update but if you will see my code, I have implemented holder.cross.setonclicklistener, and on click of that i want to do the following work which i mentioned.

Comment: For this you need selected check box position and then change background color of the selected position check this :

<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215365/select-checkbox-is-duplicated-when-scrolling-on-an-expandablelistview/46218263#46218263>