# Textwatchers causing unnecessary changes in Expandable List View

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, textwatcher

In my Expandable List View , I have EditText in each child view, I have to update the model on each text update, so I have tried to add textwatchers to each EditText. But when using with TextWatchers , my models are entered with incorrect values at group & child positions.

This is my adapter code

```
    package dularish.splitspends;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by pc on 11/3/2017.
     */

    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        public List<CardViewModel> models;
        public Context ctx;
        public ExpandableListView listviewref;



        public ExpandableListAdapter(List<CardViewModel> models, Context ctx, ExpandableListView expandableListView) {
            this.models = models;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.listviewref = expandableListView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return models.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return models.get(groupPosition).getInnerModelsData().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return models.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return models.get(groupPosition).getInnerModelsData().get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            String Name = models.get(groupPosition).getName();
            String Amount = models.get(groupPosition).getAmount().toString();
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_cardview,null);
            }
            EditText namebox = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namebox);
            EditText amountbox = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountbox);
            ImageButton dropdownbutton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dropdownbutton);
            namebox.setText(Name);
            amountbox.setText(Amount);
            //listviewref.expandGroup(groupPosition);//This comment should remind you that on every refresh this method would be executed
            dropdownbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listviewref.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
                        System.out.println("Group Collapsed");
                        Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.imagebutton_rotate_back);
                        hyperspaceJumpAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                        v.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
                        listviewref.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Group expanded");
                        Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.imagebutton_rotate);
                        hyperspaceJumpAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                        v.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
                        listviewref.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                    }

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            String SubAmount = models.get(groupPosition).getInnerModelsData().get(childPosition).getInnerAmount().toString();
            String Purpose = models.get(groupPosition).getInnerModelsData().get(childPosition).getPurpose();

            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_cardview,null);
            }
            EditText subamountbox = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subamountbox);
            EditText purposebox = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.purposebox);
            ImageButton addchildbutton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inneraddbutton);
            ImageButton deletechildbutton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.innerdeletebutton);
            subamountbox.setText(SubAmount);
            purposebox.setText(Purpose);
            System.out.println("Child set for GroupPosition - " + groupPosition + " ChildPosition - " + childPosition + " Amt " + SubAmount + " Purpose " + Purpose);

            addchildbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("AddChild button clicked");
                    models.get(groupPosition).addInnerModelsData(new InnerCardViewModel(60,"DefaultAddChild"));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            subamountbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    System.out.println("TextChanged for GroupPosition - " + groupPosition + " ChildPosition - " + childPosition + " Amt " + s.toString());
                 models.get(groupPosition).getInnerModelsData().get(childPosition).setInnerAmount(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s)));
                    //notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });/*
            purposebox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    models.get(groupPosition).getInnerModelsData().get(childPosition).setPurpose(s.toString());
                }
            });
    */
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is my Console Output without TextWatcher for Subamount EditText :

```
    11-04 08:19:52.138 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Group expanded
    11-04 08:19:52.154 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 1500 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:19:52.157 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:19:52.166 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 1500 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:19:52.174 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:19:55.548 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: AddChild button clicked
    11-04 08:19:55.561 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 1500 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:19:55.563 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:19:55.565 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 2 Amt 60 Purpose DefaultAddChild
    11-04 08:19:55.572 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 1500 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:19:55.574 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:19:55.575 30714-30714/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 2 Amt 60 Purpose DefaultAddChild
```

This is my console output with TextWatchers

```
    11-04 08:16:17.860 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Group expanded
    11-04 08:16:17.885 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 1500 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:16:17.888 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 50
    11-04 08:16:17.889 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:16:17.897 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 50
    11-04 08:16:17.897 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50
    11-04 08:16:17.897 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 50 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:16:17.906 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:16:37.699 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: AddChild button clicked
    11-04 08:16:37.717 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 50 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:16:37.719 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 50
    11-04 08:16:37.720 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 50 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:16:37.722 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.722 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.722 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 2 Amt 60 Purpose DefaultAddChild
    11-04 08:16:37.731 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.731 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.731 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.732 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 60 Purpose Default
    11-04 08:16:37.733 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.734 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 60 Purpose Trial2
    11-04 08:16:37.735 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 0 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.735 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 1 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.735 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: TextChanged for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 2 Amt 60
    11-04 08:16:37.736 27184-27184/dularish.splitspends I/System.out: Child set for GroupPosition - 0 ChildPosition - 2 Amt 60 Purpose DefaultAddChild
```

Note: I have not changed data for any EditText from UI.

Is my method of implementing TextWatchers wrong, or is there any problem with Adapter? Although I clearly mention to update TextWatcher only for the corresponding group & child positions, they are getting mixed up.

One more observation, I think convertView in the 'getChildView' returns views for all the childViews. Since I'm setting TextChangedListener to view in the convertview, could it be causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

Bind one array-list of type Boolean with your data default set all the Boolean false when user select the view set the position true so you can detect the position then work according to its position.

Also you can do with tag in XML set edit text tag like -1 and while binding data in activity
add boolean with it and when user click or select the position get position like this :

```
Integer Pos = Integer.parseInt(holder.edittext.getTag().toString());
```

and work according to the selected position then all the other views except selected will not work.

Also check this Example :

[Select checkbox is duplicated when scrolling on an ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215365/select-checkbox-is-duplicated-when-scrolling-on-an-expandablelistview/46218263#46218263)